# Restart systemd service when GPU memory limit is reached

Tags: 22.04, systemd, gpu

I'm using the following systemd service on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The service is saved in `/lib/systemd/system/myService.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=myService
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/Data

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/project/main
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StandardOutput=append:/usr/local/bin/project/stdout.log
StandardError=append:/usr/local/bin/project/stderr.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My service is using the GPU. I would like to restart the service automatically if a certain amount of GPU memory usage (vram) is reached. I could use `MemoryHigh` and `MemoryMax` but I think this is for CPU memory only.

Is it possible to automatically restart a service when GPU memory is over a limit for a certain amount of time (e.g. 1min)? Peaks should not be detected but only when memory is too high for a longer amount of time.

Do you see any other improvements of the service? I would like that the service is always running, i.e. always restarting at boot and when it crashes. I think this I already achieved with the service file.

Comment: It may help to know why you want to do this.

Comment: @David Because my service is running a Huggingface model which uses the GPU. Unfortunately, GPU memory usage increases over time. Thus, I would like to restart when a limit is reached.

Comment: systemd is a vram guzzler!  Who has allowed this to happen?  It continues to poses and consume vram , continuing to slow down a machine as time goes on and it never seems to drop the vram it has posesed , no matter if the processes are running or not.
Someone please address this issue.  systemd is a vram hog!  Why is it using vram in the first place!  Systemd is a background process! I am running Arch/Gnome with AMD Ryzen integrated graphics.  How can we refresh systemd vram without restarting our system?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to help me.

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/systemd-user-service-sporadically-uses-100-of-one-cpu-core-possibly-gnome-related/117576/9

> Hi
>
> I had the same issue and solved it by setting 2 variables in these
> files: /etc/systemd/user.conf and system.conf
>
> Changed: LogLevel=info to LogLevel=err and DefaultLimitCPU=50%
>
> CPU limit was blank and commented out. After this change, ‘systemd
> init’ and ‘systemd -user’ processes does not even register.
>
> Another symptom I had was file-browser (dolphin) will go stale on
> ‘refresh’, slowing down basic file browsing tremendously.

Now if only there was a way to limit systemd's vram usage because it is a VRAM guzzler/hog. Not sure if it is a Gnome/systemd problem but boy does it consume vram.